# Probability of arising of simple graph in configuration model

Tags: graphs, combinatorics, random-graphs

I am studying a configuration model building $d$-regular graphs and reading the following article:
[The expansion of random regular graphs](http://snap.stanford.edu/class/cs224w-readings/ellis11expansion.pdf) by David Ellis.

I am stuck on the following step:

> Each simple labelled $d$-regular graph on $n$ vertices has the same probability of arising. Indeed, it is easy to see that a simple d-regular graph on $[n]$ arises from precisely $(d!)^n$ of the matchings.

Where does this $(d!)^n$ come from?

Comment: Given one representation of a particular simple graph, how many equivalent representations are there? How would you generate them? Can you count them? If you get lost, try working out a simple example, say 2-regular simple graphs on 3 vertices.

Comment: A quite related question was posted here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/360848/probability-that-a-random-multigraph-is-simple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a simple $d$-regular graph. For each vertex, assign numbers from $1$ to $d$ to the edges adjacent to it. There are $(d!)^n$ ways to do so. Each such assignment corresponds to a particular perfect matching in the configuration model, and vice versa.